# Best way to copy from one array to another

Tags: java, arrays

When I run the following code, nothing gets copied - what am I doing wrong?

Also, is this the best/most efficient way to copy data from one array to another?

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int b[] = new int[a.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = b[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you see? Your code looks fine (are you looking for System.arraycopy()?)

Comment: @Mimi, @rsp - there's a bug in his code!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think your assignment is backwards:

`a[i] = b[i];`

should be:

`b[i] = a[i];`

Answer (score 93):

There are lots of solutions:

```
b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

Which allocates a new array, copies over the elements of `a`, and returns the new array.

Or

```
b = new int[a.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, b.length);
```

Which copies the source array content into a destination array that you allocate yourself.

Or

```
b = a.clone();
```

which works very much like `Arrays.copyOf()`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12157300/535871).

Or the one you posted, if you reverse the direction of the assignment in the loop:

```
b[i] = a[i]; // NOT a[i] = b[i];
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [Arrays.copyOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29) my friend.