# .clone() or Arrays.copyOf()?

Tags: java, immutability

In an effort to reduce mutability, should we rather use

```
public void setValues(String[] newVals) {

     this.vals = ( newVals == null ? null : newVals.clone() );
}
```

or

```
public void setValues(String[] newVals) {

     this.vals = ( newVals == null ? null : Arrays.copyOf(newVals, newVals.length) );
}
```

Comment: The above doesn't compile unless `vals` is `Object vals`. Otherwise, these are comparable approaches. `clone` is a simpler call (save for the ugly downcast).

Comment: How about `System.arrayCopy()` (which will be faster than your 2 options)?

Comment: @assylias Are you positive? `clone` should be at least as fast, it does a byte-for-byte copy of instance data.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366303/java-copy-array-of-non-primitive-type

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821851/does-calling-clone-on-an-array-also-clone-its-contents

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik See my answer - you were right.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### Update using jmh

[Using jmh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287457/829571), I get similar results, except that `clone` seems to be marginally better.

#### Original post

I ran a quick test for performance: `clone`, `System.arrayCopy` and `Arrays.copyOf` have very similar performance (jdk 1.7.06, server vm).

For details (in ms), after JIT:

> clone: 68
> arrayCopy: 68
> Arrays.copyOf: 68

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
        IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    int[] warmup = new int[1];
    warmup[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15000; i++) { // triggers JIT
        sum += copyClone(warmup);
        sum += copyArrayCopy(warmup);
        sum += copyCopyOf(warmup);
    }

    int count = 10_000_000;
    int[] array = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    // additional warmup for main
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += copyArrayCopy(array);
    }
    System.gc();
    // copyClone
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += copyClone(array);
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("clone: " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    System.gc();
    // copyArrayCopy
    start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += copyArrayCopy(array);
    }
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("arrayCopy: " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    System.gc();
    // copyCopyOf
    start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += copyCopyOf(array);
    }
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Arrays.copyOf: " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    // sum
    System.out.println(sum);
}

private static int copyClone(int[] array) {
    int[] copy = array.clone();
    return copy[copy.length - 1];
}

private static int copyArrayCopy(int[] array) {
    int[] copy = new int[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, array.length);
    return copy[copy.length - 1];
}

private static int copyCopyOf(int[] array) {
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    return copy[copy.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: ... and the conclusion is that `clone()` is the best option, being a nilary method (no parameters to screw up) which also is as typesafe as it can get (thanks to return type covariance on `clone()` for array types).

Comment: There is a junit plugin for doing benchmarks like this from Carrot Search Labs - [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html).  It makes creating micro benchmarks like this very easy.

Comment: @C.Trimble I have used [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) in the past and it works well.

Comment: Arrays.copyOf uses  System.arrayCopy  internally so no need to comparison between them.

Answer (score 7):

Please also consider the security of using "clone()".  A class of well-known attacks use classes that override objects' "clone()" methods with malicious code.  For example, CVE-2012-0507 (the "Flashback" attack on Mac OS) was addressed by basically [replacing a ".clone()" call](https://books.google.com/books?id=kSiDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=CVE-2012-0507%20flashback%20clone&source=bl&ots=YnZQ3zpBQa&sig=A68g15JAFlkjLd708nxV_M7RXSA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHoLbBifvOAhXLJsAKHa_1BrQQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=CVE-2012-0507%20flashback%20clone&f=false) with a ".copyOf" call.

Additional discussion on the obsolete-ness of "clone()" can be found on StackOverflow here: [object cloning with out implementing cloneable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192223/object-cloning-with-out-implementing-cloneable-interface)

Comment: Late but out of curiosity, is is possible to synthetically extend an Array type. Certainly you can't do it using regular Java syntax.

Comment: Looking at the case that you link too, seems strange that it would ever work.... perhaps aggressive compiler optimization may result in not checking that the value passed to ```E[]``` is in fact an array since the inlined code only executes the ```clone``` which is supported by all objects.

Comment: I see, this is in fact only possible by low-level invalid manipulation of object pointers called "***type-confusion***".

Answer (score 4):

I written a simple program to check the difference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException,
        PrinterException
{
  //Verify array remains immutable.

  String[] str =  {"a","b","c"};
  String[] strings  = str.clone();
  //change returned array
  strings[2]= "d";
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));

  String[] stringsCopy = Arrays.copyOf(str, str.length);
  stringsCopy[2]= "d";
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsCopy));

  //peformance
  long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++)
  {
      str.clone();
  }
  System.out.println("Time Required for Clone: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-before));

  //peformance
  long beforeCopy = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++)
  {
      Arrays.copyOf(str, str.length);
  }
  System.out.println("Time Required for Copy of: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-beforeCopy));

}
```

And it outputs

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
Time Required for Clone: 26288
Time Required for Copy of: 25413
```

So if you see in both case `String[]` is immutable and performance is almost same thought Arrays.copyOf() is slightly faster on my machine.

**Update**

I changed program to create large array[100 strings] rather than small array.

```
  String[] str =  new String[100];

  for(int i= 0; i<str.length;i++)
  {
      str[i]= Integer.toString(i);
  }
```

And moved `copy of` method before `clone` method. With below results.

```
 Time Required for Copy of: 415095
 Time Required for Clone: 428501
```

Which are again more of same. `Please do not ask me to run the test again as it takes a while` :(

**Update 2**

For String array `1000000` and for number of iterations `10000`

```
Time Required for Copy of: 32825
Time Required for Clone: 30138
```

`copy of` takes more time than `clone`

Comment: @assylias for Integer.MAX_VALUE ie `0x7fffffff`

Comment: I mean how many times have you run the whole benchmark? Results could vary from one run to another - Have you also made sure GC is not interering with your results?

Comment: @assylias 2 times and yes they vary but if we take an average then it is almost same for both cases.

Comment: This copies a very small array many times. It is far better to test copying of large arrays in order to stress the copying itself and not any logic surrounding it.

Comment: @AmitD Do you get the same result if you switch the loops (Arrays.copyOf first, then clone)?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik,@assylias I have updated program to address both suggestions but because of length of array is more it is taking a while. I will update the result once program finishes.

Comment: Reduce the number of iterations. You don't need billions of iterations.

Comment: A hundred elements is not exactly large, it's still smallish. Ten thousand would qualify for a medium-sized array, and a million and above would be considered large. But nevermind, your results are in line with all the other results around here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Update 2 for  array size Million.

Comment: Without careful use of `System.gc` your results can be significantly skewed. You should rerun the whole program for like ten times and see that the results are fully stable, and test that they are stable under the reordering of benchmarks (test clone first, or test copyOf first).

Comment: @AmitD From your latest updates I suppose we can conclude that the 2 methods are equivalent. +1 for the hard work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of mutability, they will provide exactly the same - shallow copy of data.

Comment: Shallow copy of immutable objects is a perfectly valid approach.

Comment: @BGR copyOf uses System.arraycopy, I guess that clone uses it as well. So they should have equal performance (still, copyOf has some additional checks for types, so it might be slightly slower)

Comment: `copyOf` needs type checking only if you specify the resulting array type. Similar for `System.arraycopy`.