# Java array modifying itself due to pass-by-something error?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm instantiating one array 'array1' by another 'array2' and then attempting to modify 'array2', which changes 'array1'. After many hours I realised that it may be a call-by- or a pass-by- ref/value error. Can someone please help me solve this and put me in the right direction?

```
    int[] src = {0,4,3,2,1};
    int[] dest = src;

    dest[0] = dest[0] + 2;

    for (int node: dest) {
        System.out.print(node + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
    for (int node: src) {
        System.out.print(node + " ");
    }
```

This produces:

2 4 3 2 1

2 4 3 2 1

i.e. the source array gets modified too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java never implicitly copies objects.

Comment: Both objects (`src` and `dest`) hold the same reference, so any change in the state on one of them will be reflected in the other.

Comment: Are you trying to modify `dest` without modifying `src`?

Comment: Create different arrays and initialize each entry with the same value. You can use [`System.arrayCopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) and save some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
int[] dest = src;
```

both variables are referencing to the same position in memory. In other words, they are referencing to the same array. You can try using `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
int[] dest = Arrays.copyOf(src, src.length);
```

**Edit:**
As @BackSlach commented, you can also use [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

```
int[] dest = src.clone(); //clone() is a method present in every object in java
```

As a third alternative you can use `System.arrayCopy()`

```
int[] dest = new int[src.length];
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, src.length);
```

Note that **[they have similar performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157504/2670792)**.

Comment: No need for `Arrays.copyOf`, just use `src.clone()`, arrays are objects in java :)

Comment: Thanks. So far Arrays.copyOf, .clone() and System.arrayCopy are being suggested. Which one is best?

Comment: You should stay away from `clone()`. Java's cloning mechanism is largely broken.

Comment: @arshajii Not really true. It's recommended to stay away from that method for objects, but for arrays it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @BackSlash You said yourself: "arrays are objects in java".

Comment: @arshajii Yes, I wanted to say that in _other_ objects it's not recommended, but for arrays it's fine

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a copy of the `src` array in `dest`, so that when you modify `dest`, you don't also modify `src`.  Just saying

```
int[] dest = src;
```

doesn't copy the array; it just creates another references to the same array.  Create a copy:

```
int[] dest = new int[src.length];
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, src.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, thats the source of your problem.

What you can do about it is to write a copy method that loops over your array and writes all the numbers to the new array.

Please keep in mind that this will only work for primitive types like `int`. If you have objects in your array, they are passed by reference aswell so deep-copying an array of any object needs some more work.

Also check out the [`clone()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) method, which can be overloaded to provide a mechanism to copy an object you're implementing.

Comment: @Christian oh, wasn't aware of that. You never stop learning, thanks for mentioning :).

Comment: _Also check out the clone() method, which can be overloaded to provide a mechanism to copy an object._ Not in this case: you can't extend array, so you can't overload (override) that method.

Comment: @BackSlash Yes I'm aware of that, but i thought it would be worth mentioning it to make the OP aware of future problems with Object copying.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with calling/passing. When you do

```
int[] dest = src;
```

then `dest` points to the same object that `src` points to. Therefore, a modification in `dest` can also be seen in `src`:

```
           +---+---+---+---+---+
src -----> | 0 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | <----- dest
           +---+---+---+---+---+


dest[0] = dest[0] + 2;


           +---+---+---+---+---+
src -----> | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | <----- dest
           +---+---+---+---+---+
```

`src[0]` is 2 now as well, even though you modified `dest`.

As has been suggested, you can use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) to produce a new, distinct array with the same contents as `src`.

```
int[] dest = Arrays.copyOf(src, src.length);
```

*Now*, we have this situation:

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+
src  -----> | 0 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+

            +---+---+---+---+---+
dest -----> | 0 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+


dest[0] = dest[0] + 2;


            +---+---+---+---+---+
src  -----> | 0 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+

            +---+---+---+---+---+
dest -----> | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
            +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Notice that the modification to `dest` did not affect `src`.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking on the right lines: everything that isn't a primitive type is passed by reference in Java.

When the following is executed, you are declaring a new reference to the same array in memory:

int[] dest = src;

So you need to declare a new array. You could then either copy the values of the elements of the first array to the second one 'manually' in a loop, or use the arraycopy method in the System namespace

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy