# Access rights of fields regarding JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Suppose I have a class which implements a stack in the style of a linked list:

```
public class Stack {
    private StackNode base;

    public void push(Object item) {
        if (base == null) {base = new StackNode(item);}
        // remaining implementation not shown
    }
}
```

and a JUnit test class for it:

```
public class TestStack {
    @Test
    public void testPush() {
        Stack st = new Stack();
        st.push(new Integer(3)); 

        assertEquals((Integer)st.base.getContents(), new Integer(3)); //Error!
        // other test cases not shown
    }
}
```

**My question is: what is the best practice for solving the issue of the test class's access rights to `base`?**

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175868/junit-test-builder-with-private-field) which discusses making an accessor, and I know that I could also put my `Stack` and `TestStack` code into a package and make the `base` field package-private.

I'm wondering what the best course of action is.  I know I shouldn't be using `pop` in `push`'s unit test, and vice versa, as this couples those unit tests.

I think that making a (public) accessor is bad practice if I don't want client code to access the field, **so is the right call to make an accessor for the field (or the field itself) package-private?**

Another informative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes) discusses options for private methods, but this is regarding a public method, and to test it I need to access a private field, so the many statements of "if you need to access private methods/classes, you're doing it wrong" doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: If you're just reading that value, why not simply implement a getter for that?

Comment: Why do you need to test that in any case? If it's a stack, isn't there a public pop() method you can call to check if it's correctly saving the value?

Comment: Test the behavior - not the implementation.  The internal guts should not matter.  You should be able to change the implementation as needed.  As long as the signature of the public method doesn't change the unit tests should not need to be changed.

Comment: Still, a nice newbie question, as you actually sat down and did some prior research. My vote for that ... have fun practicing upvoting ... and don't forget to accept the most helpful answer at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should write tests that exercise the public API. It's not always possible though. In this case I would write a test that exercises two methods together, `push` and `pop` because these two make a functional stack:

```
public class Stack {
    private StackNode base;

    public void push(Object item) {
        ...
    }

    // I know this wasn't part of your code
    public Object pop() {
        ...
    }
}

public class TestStack {
    @Test
    public void testOnePush() {
        // GIVEN
        Stack st = new Stack();

        // WHEN
        st.push(new Integer(3)); 
        Object popped = st.pop();

        assertEquals(popped, new Integer(3));
    }
}
```

If this kind of testing is not possible, then it's okay to expose `base` either directly or through a getter. In this case I prefer to write a warning comment, i.e. it's only for testing:

```
public class Stack {
    StackNode base; // package-private for testing reasons
}
```

It's possible to warn the other developers with method names too:

```
public class Stack {
    private StackNode base;

    /** For unit tests only!!! */
    public StackNode getBaseForTests() {
         return base;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, I put down the conceptual idea; you put down some code. Nice pair of answers methinks ... you got my vote for that.

Comment: And you may want to `assertSame` rather than `assertEquals` in your case. I think it would be surprising if they were different instances.

Comment: Also, adding methods specifically for testing is a *terrible* idea. Tests support the code, not the other way around. If you find your self needing to do that, you need to redesign your class.

Comment: @Michael I disagree. Everything in IT is about balancing. If adding that one package protected method makes your life 10 times easier compared to spending hours of other activities ... then that can be the right choice. It depends on the context; and on questions like "how often will this code be touched in the future" for example. One simply needs the experience to make that call to determine the "return on investment" for specific implementation choices.

Comment: So @tamas-rev what you're saying is this is **not** an instance of bad coupling to put `push` and `pop` test code in the same test case?  Even though `pop` having an issue means that my `push` tests might break, too?

Comment: @GhostCat Nah. If you need to test some implementation detail that desperately (hint: you don't) then use reflection. You would never, ever write a test that looked like that if you were writing the test *before* the class.

Comment: Reflection breaks when you do refactoring; calling a method does not. I think this is really getting into the opinion space: I avoid using *reflection* at all cost; you have a different opinion. I am simply saying that I don't agree with the "absoluteness" in your statements.

Comment: @NickZ yes. The trick is that a unit test - a really confusing term - tests a functional unit. A functional unit is something that has no exact definition. In this case though, the `push` method is meaningless without a `pop` method, so... I believe I read about this exact example in a unit testing book / blog post.

Comment: @GhostCat I recommended not to use either. See Andrew S's comment on the question. It doesn't get more succinct than that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have read a lot of question, but didn't get to the *core* of the message.

The core point is: you do **not** test **internals** of your production code. You are interested in verifying the public contract, the *what*. You want to *avoid* doing that by verifying the *how*.

In other words: if you have a class that implements a stack, then the ideal unit test for such a class ... simply checks the behavior of an object of that class. Meaning: you verify that pushing and popping values leads to the expected results. That popping an empty stack throws an exception, ... and so on.

If you really want to check the *how* part, one solution that works *without* changing access modifiers is to use Mockito and its @InjectMock annotation.

In other words: you could mock a `StackNode` object, and @InjectMock does some reflection magic to give you a `Stack` object using that mocked `StackNode`. Now you can use the Mockito verify() approach to ensure that this `StackNode` sees the calls you would expect it to see.

But of course: that means that you invest a **lot** of time and energy to write a test that *fully* depends on the implementation details of `Stack`. As soon as you decide to change it, that whole unit test will break; and you will have to completely rewrite that as well.

And that is why you prefer to test the *what*, not the *how*.

Beyond that: is is common best practice that your class under test and its test class life in the *same* package (not in the same *project*). And having a package-protected getter for a field that says `// unit test only` is an informal, but surprisingly well-working solution, too.