# System.arrayCopy is slow

Tags: java, performance, arrays

I've been trying to measure the performance of the System.arrayCopy vs Arrays.copyOf in order to choose properly one of them. Just for the sake of benchmark I added manual copy as well and the result surprised me.
Obviously I'm missing something really important, could you, please, tell me, what it is? The implementation is as follows (see first 4 methods).

```
public class ArrayCopy {

    public static int[] createArray( int size ) {
        int[] array = new int[size];
        Random r = new Random();
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            array[i] = r.nextInt();
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] copyByArraysCopyOf( int[] array, int size ) {
        return Arrays.copyOf( array, array.length + size );
    }

    public static int[] copyByEnlarge( int[] array, int size ) {
        return enlarge( array, size );
    }

    public static int[] copyManually( int[] array, int size ) {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length + size];
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    private static void copyArray( int[] source, int[] target ) {
        System.arraycopy( source, 0, target, 0, Math.min( source.length, target.length ) );
    }

    private static int[] enlarge( int[] orig, int size ) {
        int[] newArray = new int[orig.length + size];
        copyArray( orig, newArray );
        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main( String... args ) {
        int[] array = createArray( 1000000 );
        int runs = 1000;
        int size = 1000000;
        System.out.println( "****************** warm up #1 ******************" );
        warmup( ArrayCopy::copyByArraysCopyOf, array, size, runs );
        warmup( ArrayCopy::copyByEnlarge, array, size, runs );
        warmup( ArrayCopy::copyManually, array, size, runs );
        System.out.println( "****************** warm up #2 ******************" );
        warmup( ArrayCopy::copyByArraysCopyOf, array, size, runs );
        warmup( ArrayCopy::copyByEnlarge, array, size, runs );
        warmup( ArrayCopy::copyManually, array, size, runs );
        System.out.println( "********************* test *********************" );
        System.out.print( "copyByArrayCopyOf" );
        runTest( ArrayCopy::copyByArraysCopyOf, array, size, runs );
        System.out.print( "copyByEnlarge" );
        runTest( ArrayCopy::copyByEnlarge, array, size, runs );
        System.out.print( "copyManually" );
        runTest( ArrayCopy::copyManually, array, size, runs );
    }

    private static void warmup( BiConsumer<int[], Integer> consumer, int[] array, int size, int runs ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < runs; i++ ) {
            consumer.accept( array, size );
        }
    }

    private static void runTest( BiConsumer<int[], Integer> consumer, int[] array, int size, int runs ) {
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long currentCpuTime = threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        long nanoTime = System.nanoTime();
        for ( int i = 0; i < runs; i++ ) {
            consumer.accept( array, size );
        }
        System.out.println( "-time = " + ( ( System.nanoTime() - nanoTime ) / 10E6 ) + " ms. CPU time = " + ( ( threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - currentCpuTime ) / 10E6 ) + " ms" );
    }
}
```

The result shows that manual copy performed around 30% better, as shown below:

```
****************** warm up #1 ******************
****************** warm up #2 ******************
********************* test *********************
copyByArrayCopyOf-time = 162.470107 ms. CPU time = 153.125 ms
copyByEnlarge-time = 168.6757949 ms. CPU time = 164.0625 ms
copyManually-time = 116.3975962 ms. CPU time = 110.9375 ms
```

I'm really confused, because I thought (and probably I still do) that `System.arrayCopy` due to its nativity is the best possible way to copy an array, but I cannot explain this result.

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler outsmarted you, and turned your manual copy into an arraycopy, but without the Math.min, and without the extra function indirection. Also, maybe swap the order a couple times and log GC calls.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, HotSpot compiler is smart enough to unroll and vectorize manual copy loop - that's why the result code appears to be well optimized.

Why is `System.arraycopy` slower then? It is originally a native method, and you have to pay for a native call until the compiler optimizes it as JVM intrinsic.

However, in your test the compiler does not have a chance for such optimization, because `enlarge` method is not called many enough times (i.e. it is not considered as hot).

I'll show you a funny trick to force the optimization. Rewrite `enlarge` method as follows:

```
private static int[] enlarge(int[] array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { /* fool the JIT */ }

    int[] newArray = new int[array.length + size];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
    return newArray;
}
```

An empty loop triggers a backedge counter overflow, which in turn triggers the compilation of `enlarge` method. The empty loop is then eliminated from the compiled code, so it is harmless. Now `enlarge` method gets about **1.5x faster** than the manual loop!

It is important that `System.arraycopy` immediately follows `new int[]`. In this case HotSpot can optimize away the redundant zeroing of newly allocated array. You know, all Java objects must be zeroed right after creation. But as far as compiler detects that the array is filled right after creation, it may eliminate zeroing, thus making the result code yet faster.

**P.S.** @assylias' benchmark is good, but it also suffers from the fact that `System.arraycopy` is not intrinsified for the large arrays. In case of small arrays `arrayCopy` benchmark is called many times per second, JIT considers it hot and optimizes well. But for large arrays each iteration is longer, so there is a lot less iterations per second, and JIT does not treat `arrayCopy` as hot.

Comment: This reminded me of classical [*"Speed-up Loop"*](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Speedup-Loop) story :)

Comment: Thank you. I thought it might have something to do with the JIT compiler, but had no idea why. I tried to force the optimizations (there goes the warmup phase), but apparently pretty poorly.

Comment: @apangin thanks for your great details, correct me if I am wrong, as per my understanding, if any method uses empty FOR LOOP it triggers back edge counter for trigger compilation.  Meaning that during Javac process, and method 1.5x faster means execution time or else? I didn't get this point.

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan I'm talking about JIT compilation, not Javac. "Faster" here means shorter execution time.

Answer (score 8):

Using jmh, I get the results shown in the table below (size is the size of the array, score is the time in microseconds, error shows the confidence interval at 99.9%):

```
Benchmark              (size)  Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
ArrayCopy.arrayCopy        10  avgt   60      0.022 ±   0.001  us/op
ArrayCopy.arrayCopy     10000  avgt   60      4.959 ±   0.068  us/op
ArrayCopy.arrayCopy  10000000  avgt   60  11906.870 ± 220.850  us/op
ArrayCopy.clone_           10  avgt   60      0.022 ±   0.001  us/op
ArrayCopy.clone_        10000  avgt   60      4.956 ±   0.068  us/op
ArrayCopy.clone_     10000000  avgt   60  10895.856 ± 208.369  us/op
ArrayCopy.copyOf           10  avgt   60      0.022 ±   0.001  us/op
ArrayCopy.copyOf        10000  avgt   60      4.958 ±   0.072  us/op
ArrayCopy.copyOf     10000000  avgt   60  11837.139 ± 220.452  us/op
ArrayCopy.loop             10  avgt   60      0.036 ±   0.001  us/op
ArrayCopy.loop          10000  avgt   60      5.872 ±   0.095  us/op
ArrayCopy.loop       10000000  avgt   60  11315.482 ± 217.348  us/op
```

In substance, loop seems to perform slightly better than arrayCopy for large arrays indeed - probably because the JIT is quite good at optimising such a simple loop. For smaller arrays, arrayCopy seems better (although the difference is quite small).

Note however that clone seems to be consistently as good as, or better than, the other options, depending on size. So I would go for clone, which also happens to be easier to use.

---

For reference, benchmark code, run with `-wi 5 -w 1000ms -i 30 -r 1000ms -t 1 -f 2 -tu us`:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class ArrayCopy {

  @Param({"10", "10000", "10000000"}) int size;

  private int[] array;

  @Setup(Level.Invocation) public void setup() {
    array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      array[i] = i;
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public int[] clone_() {
    int[] copy = array.clone();
    return copy;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public int[] arrayCopy() {
    int[] copy = new int[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, array.length);
    return copy;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public int[] copyOf() {
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    return copy;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public int[] loop() {
    int[] copy = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      copy[i] = array[i];
    }
    return copy;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also wanted to make the new array larger, that's why I did not use clone.