# Copy 2D array in Java using streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

This question is related to [How do I copy a 2 Dimensional array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java/13792183)

But how would you copy an array using streams in Java 8 / 9?

This is what I came up with:

```
static int[][] cloneArray(int[][] array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length).collect(
            () -> new int[array.length][],
            (ints, i) -> ints[i] = array[i].clone(),
            (ints, i) -> {});
}
```

Is there a more elegant or performant way to copy a 2D array using streams?

Comment: Why do you box the ints? That's gonna kill the performance definitely.

Comment: Can't really see how this is an improvement on the various non-stream ways, unless your intention is to make your code slower and much harder to read.

Comment: @Kayaman: yes, that is silly. I have updated the question.

Comment: @khelwood; I have removed boxing. Why is performance so much slower?

Comment: I think the issue here is assuming that streams would somehow provide a better or faster way. A basic task like array copying is already solved efficiently, there are no huge advantages to be had.

Comment: @Kayaman: I was just exploring the possibility of solving this problem with streams - no explicit assumption was expressed in the question in terms of which solution is better. I agree that this problem has been already efficiently solved without streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it straight-forwardly using

```
static int[][] cloneArray(int[][] x) {
    return Arrays.stream(x).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Note that this works for any `ElementType` with a `public` method `ElementType clone()`, like

```
static ElementType[] cloneArray(ElementType[] x) {
    return Arrays.stream(x).map(ElementType::clone).toArray(ElementType[]::new);
}
```

and in your case, `ElementType` happens to be `int[]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
return Arrays.stream(x).map(r->Arrays.copyOf(r, r.length)).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

I think this is an improvement because you're not allocating a nxm array then replacing all of the m length ones with a  copy.

Comment: I like it, because it is very compact. But what about performance?

Comment: You're not double allocating in this way. You could probably improve your attempt by replacing the `.clone` call with `System.arraycopy` or at the very least, ditch the `array[0].length` and leave that part empty.

Comment: Is `.clone` slower than `System.arraycopy`? Thank you for the suggestion to leave the `array[0].length` empty.

Comment: You'll have trouble measuring the difference, as per this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157300/clone-or-arrays-copyof Although in your case for a 2D array, where each row is the same length, I suspect they `System.arraycopy` will be the fastest because it allocates everything upfront.