# Trying to figure out how many times a certain set of characters appears in a bigger one with copying Arrays. Getting an error + is this the best way?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a program that figures out how many times a certain set of characters repeats itself in a longer set of characters (several times for several different set of characters)

I tried to achieve this by "importing" the long set of characters into a char array, and then make a 2D array for all the shorter sets of characters that I want to check the occurence of.

Then, I wanted my for loop to create an "interim" array of the same length as the short arrays have and compare it to each of them, however, the program keeps returning 0 occurences no matte what... And is also taking too long to compute when checking longer arrays with loads of character sets.

```
import java.util.*;
public class A {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Preberi podatke
    int dolzinaDolgi = sc.nextInt(); //D
    int dolzinaKratki = sc.nextInt(); //d
    int stKratkih = sc.nextInt(); //n
    sc.nextLine(); // prehod v novo vrstico
    char [] Dolgi = sc.nextLine().toCharArray(); //prebrano dolgo zaporedje
    char [][] TabelaKratki = new char [stKratkih][dolzinaKratki];
    int [] results = new int [stKratkih];
    for (int i=0; i<stKratkih; i++) {
        TabelaKratki[i]=sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<dolzinaDolgi-dolzinaKratki; i++) {
        char [] vmesnoZaporedje = new char [dolzinaKratki];
        vmesnoZaporedje = Arrays.copyOfRange (Dolgi, 0+i, dolzinaKratki+i-1);
        for (int j=0; j<stKratkih; j++) {
            if (TabelaKratki [j] == vmesnoZaporedje) {
                results [j] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int index = 0; index<stKratkih; index++) {
        System.out.println(results[index]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to copy from one array to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537589/best-way-to-copy-from-one-array-to-another)

Comment: Specifically, the Arrays.copy method, not the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps regular expression is much better.
1. Convert the text to be searched into a pattern.
2. Store all different sets of characters into array.
3. Loop the array and loop to find occurrences using the pattern.

Refer to this answer for count the occurrences. [java regex match count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count)

Comment: Please show a small example of how this can be done for a part of the text

Comment: Thank you, but as this is a homework assignment, I'd much raher work with arrays - as this is what we are using now.